# CORS Configuration not working Spring WebFlux Application

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cors, spring-webflux

I tried configuring CORS using below method, it doesn't work and gives me this error, can't figure out what I am missing.

Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure,
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebFlux 
class CorsConfig() : WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(corsRegistry: CorsRegistry) {
        println("\nCORS MAPPINGS")
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
    }

}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the URL scheme not being set to either "http" or "https" for the CORS request. This error typically occurs when making requests from a URL with a different scheme (e.g., "file://"). The CORS policy does not support that.

Are you accessing your application using either "http://" or "https://" in the URL?

Comment: @YevheniiSemenov Yes, I am using https:// in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work the way you did it. This has to be set differently in WebFlux.

```kotlin
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http
            // other config
            .cors().disable()
            // other config
            .build()
    }
}
```